# Printing web page using CSS & Bootstrap - Second page margin off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the html posted below 
When I print (or print preview) the person div boxes align on page 1 correctly but on all subsequent pages the first person div box is off to the left side.

[The person box is on page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiEHd.png)

It looks like if I remove the page-break-inside: avoid from the css this goes away but then the boxes are broken on the page breaks and I want to avoid that.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.person-box {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
.FieldName {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid black;*/
}
.application-mugshot img {
  height: 105px;
  width: 105px;
}
span.application-name {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: larger;
}
span.application-address,
span.application-phone,
span.application-email {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- META TAGS -->
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0,width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1" />
  <!-- CSS FILES -->
  <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="Styles/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- HEADER -->
  <header id="header-container">

  </header>

  <!-- MAIN CONTAINER -->
  <section class="maincontainer">
    <form name="frmMain" id="frmMain">

      <div>

      </div>
      <div id="divMainWrapper" class="MainWrapper">
        <div id="divMain" class="Main">
          <div id="divContent" class="row">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>
              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-1 "></div>

              <div class="col-xs-5   person-box">
                <input name="ctl394" type="text" value="YjYJD%2fbC9%2frhmCBxZqp8TA%3d%3d" class="application-id" style="display:none;" />
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 application-mugshot">
                    <img class="MugShot img-responsive animated rubberBand" src="..\Pictures\Applications\600\default.jpg" style="border-width:0px;left:-57;" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <span class='application-name'>Smith, Joe</span><span class='application-address'>123 Main St&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>&nbsp;</span><span class='application-address'>New York, NY 13456&nbsp;</span><span class='application-phone'>(555) 555-1212&nbsp;</span>
                    <span
                    class='application-email'>joesmith@fakemail.com&nbsp;</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <!-- FOOTER -->

  </section>
  <!-- JS FILES -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/jQuery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/Common.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScripts/Forms/Application_Summary.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Here is a zip file that can be downloaded and ran locally in print preview to reproduce the issue:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9n0cy06rdo1zt8/PrintProblem.zip?dl=0

Comment: is the number of pages / entries fix? It looks like if it was in your example, just asking because a server side generation would make sense imo

Comment: Neither is fixed.  I just created enough dummy records to create two pages but with my real data I have 4 four pages of data currently

Comment: can you post the serverside generation please? for me it is easier to find the problem when i see the servercode instead of crawling through long html files ;)

Comment: Sorry but the server side code is asp.net and it for it be functional I would need to post alot more code.  The most simplified version of that code is the stripped down HTML only I posted

Comment: This might help.  I have created a zip containing the HTML, JS, CSS files that is just enough to recreate the problem.  It can be downloaded from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t9n0cy06rdo1zt8/PrintProblem.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

the bootstrap grid model does not work the way you implemented it as you can see in the documentation (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

its always the structure:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
</div>
//and so on
```

you always need to reach "12" with your colums in each row. In my example it is 1) 6+6 = 12 and 2) 2+8+2=12. You column classes need to fill the 12. Hope it helps

Comment: I added </div>
<div class="row"> to every 2 person boxes (so their column count = 12) and I am still seeing the problem on printing page 2

Comment: can you post the generated source of page 2 as a screenshot or the way you prefer?

Comment: Here is a link to the source files after changing the rows to 12 columns in length per your suggestion above.  To see the problem open the html file in the zip and print preview in your browser.  Advance to page 2.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6a5y6tq16i3bsn/PrintProblem_V2.zip?dl=0